# get NSMuatbleArray from iPhone to PHP using post and respond

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send json to php using ASIFormDataRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774201/send-json-to-php-using-asiformdatarequest)

I'm new to objective-c and iOS development.

I want to send a `NSMutableArray` to PHP from an iPhone, then get it back again and print it using NSLog to just ensure that this array has been sent successfully.

I used the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *phpUrl = @"http://dt-works.com/eman/bookMarks.php";

    NSMutableArray *arrayKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayValue1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil]; 
    NSMutableArray *arrayValue2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"11", @"22", @"33", nil]; 

    NSDictionary *theReqDictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValue1 forKeys:arrayKey];
    NSDictionary *theReqDictionary2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValue2 forKeys:arrayKey];

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:theReqDictionary1,theReqDictionary2, nil];

    NSString *jsonString = [myArray JSONRepresentation];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpUrl]];

     NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jsonString=%@&submit=", jsonString];
    //NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO]];


    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    int arraySize = [statuses count];

    NSMutableArray *number = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
    {

        NSString *onee = [status objectForKey:@"one"];
        NSString *twoo = [status objectForKey:@"two"];
        NSString *threee = [status objectForKey:@"three"];


        [number addObject:status];

        NSLog(@"------------------ from browser-----------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"myOne %@ - myTwo: %@ - myThree: %@ ",onee ,twoo, threee);

    }

    NSLog(@"size of array is: %d", arraySize);
    NSLog(@"size of them is: %d", [number count]);
}
```

In PHP I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $jsonString = $_POST['jsonString'];
        print_r($jsonString);
    }
?>
```

the output is:

```
[{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},{"one":"11","two":"22","three":"33"}]

size of array is: 0

size of them is: 0
```

and the size of array should be 2, what is the wrong in my code ???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use json_decode before print ?

Comment: I think that json_decode converts the json to array , I'm not want to decode it, I want it as [{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},{"one":"11","two":"22","three":"33"}] to parse it again and output its size

Comment: use json_decode to stock result into an Array and then use the "count" php function to know the size

Comment: how to use count php function in iPhone code ?? because I want to get the size in nslog

Answer (score 0):

Start of with doing an [`var_dump`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) in PHP instead of `print_r`. Then [decode the JSON object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)!

*Update*
After your

```
[...]
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[...]
```

Add the following:

```
SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [json objectWithString:json_string error:&jsonError];

int arraySize = [parsedJSON count];

NSMutableArray *number = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *status in parsedJSON)
{

    NSString *onee = [status objectForKey:@"one"];
    NSString *twoo = [status objectForKey:@"two"];
    NSString *threee = [status objectForKey:@"three"];


    [number addObject:status];

    NSLog(@"------------------ from browser-----------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"myOne %@ - myTwo: %@ - myThree: %@ ",onee ,twoo, threee);

}
```

I think that might work. Bit on the top of my head, but give it a try.

Comment: I think that json_decode converts the json to array , I'm not want to decode it, I want it as [{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},{"one":"11","two":"22","three":"33"}] to parse it again and output its size that it should be 2

Comment: I do not understand you, What is you want to pars again? You have now an JSON encoded string... you want to send this back to the app as a json object?

Comment: yes because I'm not find a way to ensure that the array has been sent to the php, so I use the parse to ensure that it has been sent

Comment: I tried this too, it still give me 0

Comment: What do you get if you do an NSLog on `parsedJSON`?

Comment: it tells me that it is 0

Comment: if you get 0 on `parsedJSON` something is really wrong. NSDictionary cannot be 0, it can be `nil` but it cannot be `0` or boolean `false`. What do you get if you NSLog `json_string`?

Comment: I mean [parsedJSON count] gives me 0 and if I do an NSLog on parsedJSON I get (null)

Comment: Yet, I didn't ask you about that. In order for me to help you, you need to answer my question. So, again: What do you get if you do an NSLog on `parsedJSON`?

Comment: Hence your JSON object is not set, do an NSLog on `jsonError`

Comment: it gives me the following:   Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 "Unrecognised leading character" UserInfo=0x6837cc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}

Comment: There you go. Solve that first.

Comment: yes I solved it using ASIFormDataRequest check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774201/send-json-to-php-using-asiformdatarequest