# Send json to php using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm new in iPhone and I'm trying to convert NSMutable array to json string then send this string to php file using request,  and then print it again using respond to NSLog to ensure that it has been send successfully. So I wrote the following code in viewDidLoad

```
NSString *phpUrl = @"http://dt-works.com/eman/bookMarks.php";

NSMutableArray *arrayKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayValue1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil]; 
NSMutableArray *arrayValue2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"11", @"22", @"33", nil]; 

NSDictionary *theReqDictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValue1 forKeys:arrayKey];
NSDictionary *theReqDictionary2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValue2 forKeys:arrayKey];

NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:theReqDictionary1,theReqDictionary2, nil];

NSString *jsonString = [myArray JSONRepresentation];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);



 NSDictionary *questions = nil;
NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:[phpUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link];
[request setPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"jsonString"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
NSError *error = [request2 error];
[request2 startSynchronous];

if (!error) { 
    NSData *response = [request responseData];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", questions);

}
```

and the code in bookMarks.php is:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = $_POST['jsonString'];
print_r($jsonInput);
```

but it gives me:

```
[{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},{"one":"11","two":"22","three":"33"}]
Data: (null)
```

and I want Data to be as: [{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"},{"one":"11","two":"22","three":"33"}]
how to do this??

Comment: Are you sure you need to send a json? If you reach a php form you can simply send all your vars as POST or GET it will be easier!

Comment: yes I just need to send the NSMUtableArray to php as a json not variables, I tried variables before and it works, This time I want to send the array as json,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead of posting the JSON string with a key, you need to post it as Data to your script to be read in. Currently in your script you aren't even using $handle for anything...

```
NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:[phpUrl     stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link];
[request appendPostData:[jsonString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
```

And your php code..

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
print_r($decoded);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it now prints the array, and I want to ask another question, in general is there are any mistake in  $jsonInput = $_POST['jsonString']; ?? I mean: can I use it normally later in php and decode it or there is anything wrong in it ??

Comment: I edited my answer and included decoding jsonInput to a PHP Array that you can send back to your app, where you can use a combination of NSArray and or NSDictionary to parse and use the data.